# What to keep in mind when developing for Android devices

Tags: android

I've created a handful of simple apps for Android using only emulators, but I'm curious about what the best way would be to go about developing/testing for real devices. I'd like to start as soon as possible and basically spending the least amount of money for devices to test on. My main confusion is with the myriad of different Android "flavors(?)" there are out there (stock(Google), Samsung, HTC, LG, etc.). What is the biggest cause of compatibility issues between all of these devices?

Is the biggest issue the fact that all of those devices have their own versions of Android OS and if you don't test on one, the OS may cause issues? Is it the hardware (different screen sizes/ratios, resolutions, CPUs, RAM, SD Card/no SD Card, etc.)?

I basically want to find the cheapest/simplest testing solution for getting started developing. Should I buy as many different hardware spec devices or should I buy as many different Android OS flavor devices?

I know that both are considerations when testing, but which should I keep in mind for maximum testing for the cheapest price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my opinion you must have different device in hardware and android version.
for example i have 3.2 inch device with android 2.3.1 and 800MH CPU for testing app on Poor devices also i have 4 inch device with android 4.1 and 2 core CPU and also i have 8 inch device with android 4.4 and 4 core CPU for testing app on tablet.
i think device brand its not important.
you must focus on the screen size for testing UI and also processing power, ram and heap size.

good luck